# Scrapy is skipping my deny rules

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following rules

```
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*?', deny=r'/preferences')),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*?', deny=r'/auth')),follow=True),
```

But I see the following in the logs. I have also tried it without allow= and it's still the same. Do I need to ignore these URLs from a middleware instead?

> 014-01-08 21:31:07+0100 [mybot] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://mydomain.com/preferences/language?continue_to=xxxxx> (referer: http://mydomain.com/categories/something-something-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Scrapy [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules):

> If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used,
>   according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

So, you are matching any URL in one or the other rule. Just incorporate all deny rules in one:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = (r'\/preferences', r'\/auth')))
```

Few notes:

- Deny rules are regexp patterns so you should use `\/`.
- Matches are made upon absolute url so I'd prefixed patterns with domain name like `http:\/\/mydomain.com\/preferences`
- `follow = True` if you don't use `callback` in `Rule`